# Grub rescue - Error Unknown Filesystem

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, grubrescue

I am using windows 7 ultimate and Ubuntu in my home desktop.

When my local disks were about to get filled up, I tried to delete the Ubuntu partition. I did it from windows. I right clicked on my computer->manage and partitioned. I deleted the Ubuntu partition and some local disks and then I repartitioned my harddrive.

I used my computer for about 2 hours and then shut it down. When I powered it on after sometimes it shows like error message:

```
Error:unknown filesystem. 
Grub rescue>
```

When I use `ls` command it shows like this

```
Error:unknown filesystem
grub rescue>ls
(hd0) (hd0, 10) (hd0, 9) (hd0, 8) (hd0, 7) (hd0, 6) (hd0, 5) (hd0, 2) (hd0, 1)
Grub rescue>
```

What to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reinstall your **Windows Boot-loader**. To install windows boot-loader use windows cd/live USB.

Boot into cd/usb and select your windows and use repair windows

In that goto `repair -> repair using cmd or command prompt`

Type the following commands

```
Bootrec/fixboot

Bootrec/fixmbr
```

It gives a successful messages for each command.

Restart.

You can boot into windows again.

Comment: Thanku but windows cd and live usbs are already tried. They are not booting. Is there any other way?

Comment: what do you mean they are not booting

Comment: Yes.. I tried them but. Nothing is happened when cd is inserted or usb.. .just as i told u.. .

Comment: Booting into cd/USB has nothing to do with OS problems. You should be able to boot them at system startup. http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/ht/bootcddvd.htm

Comment: Yes i know. .unable to boot in to cd or usb. I made some changes in boot menu also. But no chance... .

Comment: Did your problem solved